# Long running time at job

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I try to launch QSVM algorithm (from Qiskit example ) on all real quantum devices (that is IBM Q) and get running time 5-30 seconds on one job. But if I use `ibmq_qasm_simulator`, I get 5-20 ms (not always) on one job. I want to show comparison of time by QSVM and SVM for Big Data and I must use only real quantum devices (for QSVM). My friend did similar work and he got little running time on quantum device (`ibmq_16_melbourne`) in september (but It doesn't work today - the same longrunning time). What is changed?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The number of shots is also a factor in the running time of the circuit.

If you run a circuit with just one shot (`shots = 1`) then you will find that it uses less time than if you use 1000 shots.

Theoretically, you can extract the gate sampling time (the time to execute the particular gate) in your circuit and calculate the time you expect to run a circuit. Then multiply that by the number of shots.

Comment: I use 1 shots ant get 7.8 s. QSVM algorithm creates jobs itself. I don't control them.

Comment: Are you looking at the IBM Quantum Experience dashboard for the run time? There was a bug a month ago that displayed the wrong time unit on the dashboard.

Comment: If you mean my example on image, Yes. Thank your for information.

Comment: Hmm... But running stage does real seconds. Or it can be offset time of queue to running time.